# Realizar una asociacion en sequelize para tabla con llave primaria compuesta

Tags: sql, nodejs, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

¿Alguien me puede apoyar con la asociacion de dos tablas con una llave primaria compuesta en **sequelize**? Mi gestor de base de datos es **Postgresql**

Tengo lo siguiente:

Mi primer modelo:

```
const CoreDirectorio = sequelize.define('directorio', {
    idsucdir: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    iddir: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    nombre: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
    },
    paterno: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT
    },
    materno: {
        type:Sequelize.TEXT
    },
    fechanacimiento: {
        type: 'TIMESTAMP'
    },
    lugarnacimiento: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    }
}, {
    schema:'serveropen_public',
    timestamps: false,
    freezeTableName: true
});

export default CoreDirectorio;
```

El otro modelo es el siguiente:

```
const CoreCliente = sequelize.define('clientes', {
    idcliente: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    idsucdir: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    iddir: {
        type:Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    nick: {
        type:Sequelize.TEXT
    },
    pass: {
        type:Sequelize.TEXT
    },
    ingreso: {
        type: 'TIMESTAMP'
    },
    baja: {
        type: 'TIMESTAMP'
    }
}, {
    schema:'serveropen_public',
    timestamps: false,
    freezeTableName: true
});

CoreDirectorio.hasMany(CoreCliente, { foreignKey: 'idsucdir'})
CoreCliente.belongsTo(CoreDirectorio, { foreignKey: 'idsucdir'})

CoreDirectorio.hasMany(CoreCliente, { foreignKey: 'iddir'})
CoreCliente.belongsTo(CoreDirectorio, { foreignKey: 'iddir'})

export default CoreCliente;
```

En el Modelo `CoreDirectorio` tengo mi llave primaria compuesta por dos campos (`idsucdir`, `iddir`) y necesito relacionarlo con el modelo `CoreCliente`, para que en `CoreCliente` aparezcan como llaves foraneas.

La consulta que intento realizar es la siguiente:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM clientes as c
    LEFT JOIN directorio as d USING(idsucdir,iddir)
   LIMIT 100
```